# List Index out of range error: python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
import MySQLdb
import pyodbc


typesFile = open('servinfo.txt', 'r').readlines()
dataTypes = dict((row.split(',')[0].strip(),row.split(',')[1].strip()) for row in typesFile)   


conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS}; SERVER=prsoft; DATABASE=blueseas; UID=sa;    PWD=tiger')
msCursor = conn.cursor()


db = MySQLdb.connect(passwd="pr", db="tenable")
myCursor = db.cursor()

msCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM airlinemaster WHERE type='U'") 
dbTables = msCursor.fetchall()
noLength = [56, 58, 61] 

for tbl in dbTables:
msCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM airlinemaster WHERE airline = air india('%s')" % tbl[0]) #syscolumns: see sysobjects above.
columns = msCursor.fetchall()
attr = ""
for col in columns:
colType = dataTypes[str(col.xtype)] 


if col.xtype == 60:
    colType = "float"
    attr += col.name +" "+ colType + "(" + str(col.length) + "),"
elif col.xtype in noLength:
    attr += col.name +" "+ colType + ","
else:
    attr += col.name +" "+ colType + "(" + str(col.length) + "),"

attr = attr[:-1]
myCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE " + tbl[0] + " (" + attr + ");") #create the new table and all columns
msCursor.execute("select * from %s" % tbl[0])
tblData = msCursor.fetchall()

#populate the new MySQL table with the data from MSSQL
for row in tblData:
fieldList = ""
for field in row:
    if field == None: 
    fieldList += "NULL,"
    else:
    field = MySQLdb.escape_string(str(field))
    fieldList += "'"+ field + "',"

fieldList = fieldList[:-1]
myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + tbl[0] + " VALUES (" + fieldList + ")" )
```

I'v tried the above code in many ways to import data.. but still keep on getting error as list index out of range.. Dont know where I'm going wrong.. how do I solve this?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\programs new\codes.py", line 10, in <module>
 dataTypes = dict((row.split(',')[0].strip(),row.split(',')[1].strip()) for row in typesFile)
 File "C:\Python27\programs new\codes.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
 dataTypes = dict((row.split(',')[0].strip(),row.split(',')[1].strip()) for row in typesFile)
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

pls help.... thnx in advance..

Comment: Show us your `servinfo.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least one `row` in `typesFile` that does not have a `,` comma in it:

```
>>> 'line without a comma'.split(',')
['line without a comma']
>>> 'line without a comma'.split(',')[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If `servinfo.txt` is supposed to be a comma-separated file with two columns, why not use the `csv` module to read it instead?

```
import csv
csvreader = csv.reader(open('servinfo.txt', 'rb'))
dataTypes = dict(csvreader)
```

That won't solve your issue with there being a line with no comma in it in that file though, you'll have to fix that first.

Comment: now when i tried this code.. I got an error as..                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\programs new\codes.py", line 8, in <module>
   dataTypes = dict(csvreader)
   ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2   is required.    I'm new to python.. plz be specific.. thnx -Martijn Pieters

Comment: @priya: That's the line without a comma. You need to check your `servinfo.txt` file and ensure that there are *exactly 2* columns on *each* line.